# Given Gram matrix $A A^T$, how to recover matrix $A$?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Given an $n \times n$ Gram matrix, $A A^T =: G$, whose columns are linearly independent, how can one find the original matrix $A$? Is this even possible?

---

From my research, I have seen people using eigenvectors and eigenvalues, but I still do not understand how to construct the original matrix. I am very new at linear algebra. I am trying to understand Gram matrices right now.

Comment: you can't.  For any satisfactory $A$ you can right multiply it by arbitrary orthogonal $Q$ and $AQ$ is satisfactory as well.

Comment: Note that both $\pm A$ produce the same Gram matrix.

Comment: is $\quad A\quad$ guaranteed to be unique?  I don't think so.

Comment: You can only determine $A$ up to a right-multiplication of orthogonal matrix. In other words, if $G=AA^T$ is nonsingular, the set of solutions to the equation $XX^T=G$ is given by $\{X:\,X=AQ,\ Q\in O(n,\mathbb R)\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, $A$ is not uniquely determined by $G = A A^T$. If you compute the eigendecomposition $G = UDU^T$, where $U$ is orthogonal and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries, which is always possible by the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem), then you can take $A = U \sqrt{D}$ where $\sqrt{D}$ means take square roots of the diagonal entries (and it doesn't matter which signs you choose). This gives

$$A A^T = U \sqrt{D} \sqrt{D}^T U^T = UD U^T = G$$

as desired.

Comment: Just to confirm, does the matrix U corresponds to the eigenvalues of the diagonal matrix?

Comment: @MananVij: the diagonal entries of $D$ are the eigenvalues and $U$ is the matrix whose columns are the (orthonormal) eigenvectors.